# Assign values to a empty matrix from other matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, assign

I have one empty matrix which I would like to fill in with the values of two other matrix. 
This is my empty matrix:

```
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod <- matrix(NA, nrow = 16, ncol = 13)
colnames (Att_table_S01_E031_Mod) <- c("ID", "Area", "LU_1990", "LU_2000", "LU_2005", "CHLU_90_00", "CHLU_00_05", "Tile", "Unique_ID", "D_90_00", "D_00_05", "Source_90_00", "Source_00_05")
```

The other two matrix contain the information I want to include in this new matrix such as `ID`, `Area`, `LU_1990` and so on. However, I have not found a way to do it yet. Some hints would be well appreciated.

The matrix Att_table_S01_E031 seems to have only one column. Do you know how can I split it?  [1] "ID.Area_ORG.LU_1990.LU_2000.CHLU_90_00.LU_2005.CHLU_00_05.Tile.UNIQ_ID.AREA.D_90_00.D_00_05.Sour_90_00.Sour_00_05.Conf_90_00.Conf_00_05"

Comment: Please provide reproducible examples of the other matrices too.

Comment: This is one: z <- extract(x=rc_GLC2000_LC, y=Deforested_areas) # this will return a list of vectors (one vector of all values of r for each feature in s)

# make a function that takes the majority of a vector x
z <- extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=Deforested_areas)
maj <- function(x){
  y <- as.numeric(names(which.max(table(x))))
  return(y)
}

# returns one value (the majority) per feature
z <- extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=Deforested_areas, fun=maj)
colnames (z) <- c("LU_2000")

Comment: And the second one: Att_table_S01_E031 <- as.matrix(Att_Table_Deforested_areas)

Comment: For instance, I want to use the value included in the first column of the first matrix to the fourth column of the new matrix.

Comment: note that when asked to provide more code in your question, its better to edit your question than to add in-line code into a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complementary matricies,

```
columnsToTransfer <- c('ID','Area','Tile','Unique_ID','LU_1990')
otherColumns <- colnames(Att_table_S01_E031_Mod)[!(colnames(Att_table_S01_E031_Mod) %in% columnsToTransfer)]
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod[,columnsToTransfer] <- table2[,columnsToTransfer]
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod[,otherColumns] <- table3[,otherColumns]
```

if the two smaller matricies aren't going to completely fill the big matrix,

```
columnsToTransfer1 <- c('ID','Area','Tile','Unique_ID')
columnsToTransfer2 <- 'LU_2000'
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod[,columnsToTransfer1] <- table2[,columnsToTransfer1]
Att_table_S01_E031_Mod[,columnsToTransfer2] <- table3[,columnsToTransfer2]
```

Comment: If I replace table 2 and table 3 with my other two matrix, I have this error message: Error in Att_table_S01_E031[, columnsToTransfer] : 
  subscript out of bounds Do you know what is the reason for it?

Comment: looks like you don't have 'ID','Area','Tile', and 'Unique_ID' as column names. Check colnames(Att_table_S01_E031_Mod). Are they all there?

Comment: Yes there are but in the matrix z I have only one column with LU_2000 and in the matrix Att_table_S01_E031 I have more columns than the new matrix (Att_table_S01_E031_Mod)

Comment: Basically, the columns ID', 'Area', 'LU_1990', 'Tile', 'Unique_ID' from the matrix Att_table_S01_E031 have to be transferred to the new matrix and the column LU_2000 from the matrix z has to be transferred to the new matrix.

Comment: colnames (z)
[1] "LU_2000"

Comment: colnames (Att_table_S01_E031_Mod)
 [1] "ID"           "Area"         "LU_1990"      "LU_2000"      "LU_2005"      "CHLU_90_00"  
 [7] "CHLU_00_05"   "Tile"         "Unique_ID"    "D_90_00"      "D_00_05"      "Source_90_00"
[13] "Source_00_05"

Comment: oh ok, so there are columns in the new matrix that will remain NA. I thought that the two existing matricies would fill in the big matrix completely.
I'll edit.